# worklight 6.2 Unknown realm [myRealm]. null returned for key: userName

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

I have implemented a custom loginmodule and have successfully logged in using WL.ClientLogin('myRealm'). The challengehandler in the single page app changes the view to the app start page on authstatus complete. On the new page I wish to add the authenicated user id to the header. I call WL.Client.getLoginName('myRealm) and it returns unknown realm. I have already tried  WL.Client.updateUserInfo().

Comment: Try getUserID() instead.

Comment: that's funny - same problem occurs

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WL.Client.getUserName() only after you are authenticated. So you have to use Adapter-Based authentication or Form-Based authentication or Custom-Based authentication.
For more information about using Worklight authentication look here:
https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/authentication-security/